# Machine Readable Scanner (MRZ) Cordova Plugin for IBM Mobilefirst 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I am looking for a Passport/Document ID phonegap plugin which can be integrated wth IBM MobileFirst 7.1 hybrid mobile application. It would be great if any can suggest few plugins , even if its paid version. However it needs to scan through camera and provide data.

Comment: The plugin should use the phone's camera and scan what exactly? The photograph? The text?

Comment: The plugin should scan the something like Machine Readable Zone such as Passport or any Document ID and provide the details of the data including the scanned image

Comment: @VivinK, he's looking for something like BlinkID, but that requires Cordova 7, which obviously Mobile Foundation 7.1 doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

You can search [Apache Cordova plugins repository](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) for the plugins.

Please note that MFP 7.1 packs an older version of Cordova. You can use MFP 7.1 Cordova CLI to add Cordova plugins directly.